# add alias in front of each URL mod_rewrite apache

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

If any likes come in the format

```
http://localhost/index.php/bla...
```

I want to convert it to `http://localhost/er/index.php/bla...`

I'm trying the following but it seems to be looping the url indefinitely

```
RewriteRule  ^localhost/index/php/(.*)$  localhost/er/index.php/$1  [R=301,L]
RedirectMatch  301  ^/localhost/index.php/(.*)$  localhost/er/index.php/$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 2 different things going on, a `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) and a `RedirectMatch` (mod_alias). You'll only need one, but neither of those can match against the hostname (localhost). If this has to only be limited to the "localhost" host, then you need to do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php/(.*)$ /er/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Otherwise, you can just stick with mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php/ /er/index.php/
```

Everything after `/index.php/` will automatically get appended.